# Refresh a Complex Materialized View

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a materialized view and I used some joins for it's statement. And now I have a refresh problem with it. It takes too long time (even more than an hour).

I want to have all data but refresh last 2 day's data. Is there any solution for my problem?

thanks.

Comment: Hi,
I work in a situation like yours.

I think it's very important an initial good analisys to construct Materialized View. What's the configuration of Materilized View? The Cardinality of data?

Comment: Hi @m.genova, I read oracle documents and tried to use 'Fast Refresh Method' in different methods for my materialized view, it didn't work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to tune the Materialized View Query? your problem can be related to this query (to select data) so your problem can be related to low performance of this query. The first step is to evaluate the performance of query out of Materilized View

Comment: Yes, I simplify the Materialized View Query. But it is not a permanent solution for me. I should find a permanent solution.

Comment: I found in "ASK TOM" web site different tips and tricks to construct a feasible way to manage Materialized Views.

Comment: I tried @nelucon 's answer and it worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To improve the performance of your query try google for "improving query performance". There are a few tips you might want to know. (or I could suggest you some if you want)

IF and only if the performance of your query cannot be improved, this is my suggestion:
Create 2 materialized views: 
One of them keeping all data except last 2 days and create a job to refresh it over the night. 
The other one keeping only the data for the last 2 days. You may refresh it when you want and probably might work much faster.
Then create an union view between these 2 views.

Comment: Thank you so much, I applied your second suggestion. It works for now :)